# Firebase Analytics for Web: Clean up screen tracking in funnels

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics in a React Native app (running on iOS, Android, web). I'm trying to build a funnel - but when building a funnel I'm getting multiple screen events (on web).

Currently I'm trying to disable page_views like this:

```
gtag('config', MEASUREMENT_ID, {
  anonymize_ip: true,
  send_page_view: false,
})
```

and I'm sending my events like this:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const webAnalytics = getAnalytics(app)

logEvent(webAnalytics, 'screen_view', {
  firebase_screen: currentRouteName,
  firebase_screen_class: currentRouteName,
})
```

From what I can see only one request is sent for each screen view, and it includes both the firebase_* params as well as page_title and page_location. But in the funnel (see screenshot) it gives me duplicates. I want to get completely rid of the "page title"-based in the funnel since they mess up the funnel.

I'm not sure if I need to (1) do something more to prevent page_title from being sent altogether or (2) can do something else to prevent the funnel from duplicating this. Any ideas?

[image]